# python: how to check elements in a string are extracted from another string and the occurrence are in order?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I want to check whether the string `'abc'` is extracted from the string `'baasdbiomccsjp'`, and the order of the occurrence is taken into account, that is to say `abc` is extracted by dropping `b`, `asd`, `iom`, and `csjp` from  `'b [a]  asd  [b] iom [c]   csjp'`. But if the second string is `'bccaasdbiomsjp'`, though the elments in the string 'abc' are all in the string `'bccaasdbiomsjp'`, but since the order of the occurrence of the `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` are different, then say `'abc'` is not extracted from `'bccaasdbiomsjp'` when taking account the order of the occurrence.

Now we have  s1 = `'abc'` and s2 = `'baasdbiomccsjp'`, how to check whether `s1` is extacted from `s2` and also the occurrence of the elements are in order?

My codes are here:

```
s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'baasdbiomccsjp'

#Firstly, I want to extract all the elements in s1 that also in s2
s3 = ''.join(x for x in s2 if x in s1) 
s3
'baabcc
```

I got stuck after I got all the elements from `s1` based on `s2`. The probelm is that the order of the occurrence is really hard to check.

Comment: From the duplicate: `s2_iter = iter(s2)`, then `all(c in s2_iter for c in s1)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I google a lot but not find the solution, thank you so much.